# Can Nullable types be sent through Protocol Buffers?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

The [Proto3 C# Reference](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated#wrapper_types) contains the following text:

> **Wrapper Type Fields**
>
> Most of the well-known types in proto3 do not affect code generation,
>   but the wrapper types (StringWrapper, Int32Wrapper etc) change the
>   type and behaviour of the properties.
>
> All of the wrapper types that correspond to C# value types
>   (`Int32Wrapper`, `DoubleWrapper`, `BoolWrapper` etc) are mapped to
>   `Nullable<T>` where `T` is the corresponding non-nullable type. For
>   example, a field of type `DoubleValue` results in a C# property of type
>   `Nullable<double>`.
>
> Fields of type `StringWrapper` or `BytesWrapper` result in C# properties
>   of type `string` and `ByteString` being generated, but with a default
>   value of `null`, and allowing `null` to be set as the property value.
>
> For all wrapper types, null values are not permitted in a repeated
>   field, but are permitted as the values for map entries.

When trying to generate a `.cs` file from a `.proto` file, If I try to declare a field as `Int32Wrapper` in the `.proto` file, protoc.exe throws an error about `Int32Wrapper` not existing.

```
syntax ="proto3";
package prototest;
import "MessageIdentifier.proto";


message TestMessage {
    string messageTest = 1;
    fixed64 messageTimestampTicks = 2;
    uint32 sequenceNumber = 3;
    MessageUniqueID uniqueID = 4;
    Int32Wrapper nullableInt = 5; 
}
```

It seems there is some additional step that is missing here, does anyone know how to enable these types?

Comment: Declaring a field is ambiguous, are you defining a proto file and generating C# class or defining a field in a C# class and attempting to generate a proto? A simple example might help to clarify.

Comment: @Guvante I am trying to generate .cs files from .proto files using protoc.exe. I have edited my question to add some more detail and an example .proto file.

Comment: Weird I can't find any general documentation about Int32Wrapper outside that page and a test case for protobuf: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/testdata/wrappers.proto

Comment: @Guvante That is really odd. I thought I had to be missing something, but maybe it's just a case of bad documentation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I will try to improve Nick's answer as it hasn't helped me.
grpc compiler claimed that he has no information on `google.protobuf.Int32Wrapper` type. I have found it is actually called [`google.protobuf.Int32Value`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/48234f5f012582843bb476ee3afef36cda94cb66/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto#L88), though google calls it `Int32Wrapper` in the docs.
So the code that helped me was the following:

```protobuf
...
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
...
message TestMessage {
    ...
    google.protobuf.Int32Value nullableInt = 5; 
}
```

Other links:

- [C# lib source](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/48234f5f012582843bb476ee3afef36cda94cb66/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/WellKnownTypes/Wrappers.cs#L781)
- [C# doc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/int32-value)

Comment: Not the answer. The question is 'does it transmit nullables'. This solution does not transmit null fields.

Answer (score 11):

In respect that https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto

You need to import google/protobuf/wrappers.proto in order for this to work.

```
syntax ="proto3";
package prototest;
import "MessageIdentifier.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message TestMessage {
    string messageTest = 1;
    fixed64 messageTimestampTicks = 2;
    uint32 sequenceNumber = 3;
    MessageUniqueID uniqueID = 4;
    google.protobuf.Int32Value nullableInt = 5; 
}
```

You can then use it as an int? ,eg nullableInt.HasValue and nullableInt.Value