# Can a GRPC service return a list with nulls in it?

Tags: c#, grpc, protobuf-net

I have a service that I'm hosting using various different protocols on different ports (Rest on 5000, protobuf-net with Grpc.Core on 12000, WcfCore with net.tcp bindings on 19000, protobuf-net with Grpc.AspNetCore.Server on 26000).

The service returns a `List<string>` and if the list is filled up (e.g. `{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", }`) it works on all of the services. Once the list gets a null in it (e.g. `{ "1", "2", null, "3", "4", "5", null }`), the Grpc services (ports 12000 and 26000) both fail. Is this an invalid thing to transmit over Grpc?

I'm not sure it needs to be said, but as long as it is instantiated strings, it works. So, to take the example above, if I replace the nulls with empty strings, `{ "1", "2", "", "3", "4", "5", "" }`, that works.

Comment: Scalar types (such as `string`) can't be null in protobuf. You could use the empty string (`""`) which is the default value. Google provides [Well-Known Types (WKT)](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/) that include wrappers for the scalar types (such as [`StringValue`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#string-value) for `string`). These enable the equivalent of null. Some protobuf language SDKs compile these WKTs to nullable types.

Comment: Since `protoc` [3.15.0](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.15.0), the `optional` keyword has been added to `proto3` (it is available in `proto2`) and boxes scalars in a similar way to WKTs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615583/can-nullable-types-be-sent-through-protocol-buffers Take a look i guess it is answered here

Answer (score 0):

I believe this covers it: [Support for null values and empty collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protobuf-net), see the section *Collections* about halfway down. It looks like it was [added](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net/releasenotes) in version [3.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/3.2.0) at the beginning of the year or thereabouts.

Read the page, but for a summary this is the example:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
class SomeMessage
{
    // *similar* to (but with field-presence)
    // repeated .google.protobuf.Int32Value values = 6;
    [ProtoMember(6), NullWrappedValue]
    public List<int?> Ids {get;} = new();

    // likewise, but using field-presence in an artifical
    // message type that has: SomeOtherMessage value = 1;
    [ProtoMember(7), NullWrappedValue]
    public List<SomeOtherMessage> Items {get;} = new();

    // as with Items, but applied to the value portion of the
    // key/value pairs
    [ProtoMember(8), NullWrappedValue]
    public Dictionary<int, SomeOtherMessage> KeyedItems {get;} = new();
}
```